# Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 doesn't start the new Web UI

Tags: spring, spring-roo

According with this [guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/blob/master/web-ui/README.adoc), after start Spring Roo, the new [Web UI](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3629) is available at http://localhost:9191/eastern-grey-ui/ , but the URL doesn't response, and the port 9191 isn't opened in the host.

Is there any special parameter to start Roo with that interface? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in the Spring Roo project.

By the moment, the Spring Roo Web UI is not finished, so it has not been included in the 2.0.0.RC1. Also, we don't know if it will be included into the 2.0.0.RELEASE version.

All contributions are welcome!

Hope it helps,

Regards,